# What to create a long stretched arrow across columns in latex?

Tags: tables, arrows, multicolumn, xrightarrow, witharrows

Want to enter an arrow that stretches from columns 3-5. The desired output is shown in the image file. Please suggest how to achieve it. The sample latex code I have presented below.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}     
\usepackage[english]{babel}         
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}            
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\begin{frame}{Comparison}\scriptsize\centering\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}
    \begin{tabular}{l c c c c c}
        & Project & Job-shop & Batch & Assembly & Continuous \\
        \hline 
        Flexibility &  \onslide<2->{High} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{ \onslide<2->{$\longleftarrow$}}  & \onslide<2->{Low} \\
        Variety &  \onslide<3->{High} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{ \onslide<3->{$\longleftarrow$}}  & \onslide<3->{Low} \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Also, I want the content within onslide to appear in alert format. The sample arrow style is presented below.

[image]

Comment: Please expand your code, so we can copy and compile it.

Comment: I have included the complete code. Thanks.

Comment: We are moving from „a bit“ to „overdone“. What do you need all those packages etc. for wrt this problem? Please remove what‘s not needed or distracting for your question.

Comment: Done. I have shortened the code.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with `nicematrix` using `CodeAfter`. You can add any `TikZ` attributes to the arrows that you wish.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer} 

\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\mode<presentation>

\usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structuresmallcapsserif}
\usepackage{charter} % serif

\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]

\begin{frame}{Comparison}\scriptsize\centering\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}
    \begin{NiceTabular}{l c c c c c}
        & Project & Job-shop & Batch & Assembly & Continuous \\
        \hline 
        Flexibility &  \onslide<2->{High} & & & & \onslide<2->{Low} \\
        Variety &  \onslide<3->{High} & & & & \onslide<3->{Low} \\
      \CodeAfter
      \onslide<2->{\tikz\draw[blue,<-] (2.5-|3) -- (2.5-|6);}
      \onslide<3->{\tikz\draw[<-] (3.5-|3) -- (3.5-|6);} 
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\leftarrowfill`

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]

\begin{frame}{Comparison}
  \scriptsize
  \centering
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}

  \begin{tabular}{l c c c c c}
              & Project & Job-shop & Batch & Assembly & Continuous \\
  \hline
  Flexibility &
    \onslide<2->{High} &
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\onslide<2->{\leftarrowfill}} &
    \onslide<2->{Low} \\
  Variety     &
    \onslide<3->{High} &
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{\onslide<3->{\leftarrowfill}} &
    \onslide<3->{Low} \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Avoid `utf8x`: it's unmaintained and not really compatible with recent LaTeX versions.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility with `pstricks`, which requires a very short code:

```
    \documentclass[aspectratio=169, svgnames]{beamer} % Document class
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage[english]{babel} % Set language
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{pst-node}

    \mode<presentation> % Set options
    {
      \usetheme{default} % Set theme
      \usecolortheme{rose} % Set colors
      \usefonttheme{default} % Set font theme
      \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered] % Set caption to be numbered

    }

    \usefonttheme[onlylarge]{structuresmallcapsserif}
    \usepackage{graphicx} % For including figures
    \usepackage{booktabs, caption} % For table rules
    \usepackage{hyperref} % For cross-referencing

    \setbeamertemplate{footnote}{%
        \parindent 1em\noindent%
        \raggedright
        \insertfootnotetext\par%
    }
    \usepackage{fontawesome}
    \usepackage{charter} % serif
    \hypersetup{
        pdfnewwindow=true, % links in new window
        colorlinks=true, % false: boxed links; true: colored links
        linkcolor=gray!20!black, % color of internal links 20% gray and 80%black
        citecolor=blue, % color of links to bibliography
        filecolor=magenta, % color of file links
        urlcolor=violet % color of external links
    }

    \usepackage{colortbl}
    \usepackage{pdflscape,array,booktabs}
    \usepackage[font=scriptsize]{caption}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
    \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{listings}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
    \usepackage{multirow,makecell}
    \usepackage{apacite}
    \usepackage{natbib}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \setbeamerfont{section in toc}{size=\scriptsize}
    \setbeamerfont{subsection in toc}{size=\scriptsize}

    \begin{document}

    \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]

    \begin{frame}{Comparison}\scriptsize\centering\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}
        \begin{tabular}{l c c c c c}
            & Project & Job-shop & Batch & Assembly & Continuous \\
            \hline
            Flexibility & \onslide<2->\rnode{H}{High} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{ } & \onslide<2->\rnode{L}{Low} \\
            Variety & \onslide<3->{High} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{ } & \onslide<3->{Low} \\

        \end{tabular}
    \psset{arrowinset=0.1}
    \ncline[nodesep=3pt, linecolor=CornflowerBlue]{->}{L}{H}
    \end{frame}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With `tikzmark`:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}     
\usepackage[english]{babel}         

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
    myarrow/.style={
        -Straight Barb,
        blue,
        thick, 
        shorten <=2pt,
        shorten >=2pt
        }
    }

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\begin{frame}{Comparison}\scriptsize\centering\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}
    \begin{tabular}{l c c c c c}
        & Project & Job-shop & Batch & Assembly & Continuous \\
        \hline 
        Flexibility &  \onslide<2->{\tikzmarknode{fh}{High}} & && & \onslide<2->{\tikzmarknode{fl}{Low}} \\
        Variety &  \onslide<3->{\tikzmarknode{sh}{High}} & && & \onslide<3->{\tikzmarknode{sl}{Low}} \\
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \onslide<2->{\draw[myarrow] (fl) to (fh);}
        \onslide<3->{\draw[myarrow] (sl) to (sh);}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]